# Montando um Array CAKEPHP

Tags: php, array, cakephp-2

Galera, preciso de uma ajuda pra montar um array do mau aqui. Peguei um calendário(bootstrap calendar) pronto e estou tentando implementar ele no meu site com Cakephp. Tudo certo com o layout mas na hora de buscar as informações no banco ele espera receber um Array da seguinte forma:

```
{"success":1,"result":[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Teste","title":"Teste","2":"Apenas para Teste","body":"Apenas para Teste","3":".\/descripcion_evento.php?id=1","url":".\/descripcion_evento.php?id=1","4":"event-important","class":"event-important","5":"1443105000000","start":"1443105000000","6":"1443112800000","end":"1443112800000"}]}
```

No calendar original ele monta da seguinte forma:

```
if ($conexion->query($sql)->num_rows) { 
    $datos = array(); 

    $i=0;

    $e = $conexion->query($sql); 

    while($row=$e->fetch_array())
    {
        $datos[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode(               
            array(                  
                "success" => 1,     
                "result" => $datos  
            )                      
        );
}
```

Mas não tem cristo que eu consiga fazer isso pelo cakephp. o melhor resultado que tive foi esse:

```
{"success":1,"result":[{"Agenda":{"id":"1","title":"teste","body":"teste","url":"teste","class":"event-important","start":"1443105000000","end":"1443112800000","0":"1","1":"teste","2":"teste","3":"teste","4":"event-important","5":"1443105000000","6":"1443112800000"}}]}
```

Meu controller ficou assim:

```
public function obter_eventos(){
    $datos = $this->Agenda->find('all');

    foreach ($datos as $key => $dato) {
        foreach ($dato as $value) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($value as $valor) {
                $datos[$key]['Agenda'][$i] = $valor;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode(              
        array(                  
            "success" => 1,     
            "result" => $datos  
        )                       
    );

    $this->autoRender=false;
}
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Você pode postar o resultado de um `var_dump` da variável `$datos`?

Comment: Do Model: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Agenda' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'body' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'url' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'class' => string 'event-important' (length=15)
          'start' => string '1443105000000' (length=13)
          'end' => string '1443112800000' (length=13)

Comment: Depois do Model : array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Agenda' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'body' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'url' => string 'teste' (length=5)
          'class' => string 'event-important' (length=15)
          'start' => string '1443105000000' (length=13)
          'end' => string '1443112800000' (length=13)

Comment: Rodrigo, consegue esse mesmo `var_dump` quando vem mais de um registro da consulta? Tira ele logo depois da consulta, depois da linha `$datos = $this->Agenda->find('all');` faz o `var_dump` do resultado.

Comment: Ele monta normalmente os 2 array, não da pra colocar aqui pois excede o tamanho de caracteres.

Comment: Rodrigo ali na linha `"result" => $datos` troca por `"result" => $datos['Agenda']`. Acho que já resolve teu problema, se der certo me avisa pra mim publicar como resposta.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta, é só clicar em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/88549/edit) logo abaixo dela. Mas faz esse teste que eu disse aqui antes...

Comment: Estranho ele retornou null

{"success":1,"result":null}

Comment: Ou você mudou alguma coisa, ou me passou um `var_dump` diferente do que tem na variável.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas pra ficar registrado e Agradecer o Kadu, ficou assim a solução deste problema.

```
public function obter_eventos(){
    $datos = $this->Agenda->find('all');

    foreach ($datos as $key => $dato) {
        foreach ($dato as $value) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($value as $putoti => $valor) {
                $dados[$key][$i] = $valor;
                $dados[$key][$putoti] = $valor;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(              
        array(                  
            "success" => 1,     
            "result" => $dados
        )                       
    );

    $this->autoRender=false;
```